# Stopping the WinPcap Packet capture service

Tags: windows-xp, service, wireshark, winpcap

I just installed WireShark, which also installed WinPcap.

During the installation it said "do you want xxx to start automatically", which I answered yes.

Now I would like to stop the service when I am not running wireshark, but cannot find a service in the list with name wireshark or winPcap.

Is there a service that I can stop? Or do I need uninstall WireShark?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The WinPCap services is known as "NPF" (NetGroup Packet Filter), you can start/stop it on command line with

```
c:\>net start npf
The NetGroup Packet Filter Driver service was started successfully.

C:\>net stop npf
The NetGroup Packet Filter Driver service was stopped successfully.
```

To find it in a GUI, you'll have to open `"Properties"` for `"My Computer"`, then select the `"Hardware"` tab, open `"Device Manager"`.
Here, select `View -> Show hidden devices`, open up Non-Plug and Play Drivers, right-click on `NetGroup Packet Filter Driver` and select `Properties` from the menu, thus you will get a `"NetGroup Packet Filter Driver Properties"` window.

Comment: Can I find NPF service in GUI, in `Services` applet?

Comment: @Dims : I updated my answer for the GUI part.

Answer (score 9):

Other commands that may be of interest are:

#### Change NPF to run manually

sc config npf start= demand

#### Change NPF to run automatically at boot

sc config npf start= auto

Comment: Can I find NPF somewhere in GUI?

Comment: See the answer by Cédric Julien, you can use the device manager.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've always found the command line method to be simpler, there is a GUI way to do this too.

In device manager, select "Show Hidden Devices" on the view menu, then under "Non-Plug and Play Drivers", the "NetGroup Packet Filter Driver" is listed. Double-click or right-click and select "Properties"

On the "Driver" tab of the properties page, the current status and "Start" or "Stop" buttons are displayed.